# Make forEach asynchronous in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I'm trying to understand the asynchronous programming Node.js but stalled on this code.

This function in their callback returns an array of files in a directory:

```
function openDir(path, callback) {
    path = __dirname + path;
    fs.exists(path, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                var result = [];
                files.forEach(function (filename, index) {
                    result[index] = filename;
                });
                return callback(result);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But when I use asynchronous code inside`.forEach`, it returns nothing:

```
function openDir(path, callback) {
    path = __dirname + path;
    fs.exists(path, function (exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                var result = [];
                files.forEach(function (filename, index) {
                    fs.stat(path + filename, function (err, stats) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        result[index] = filename;
                    });
                });
                return callback(result);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I understand why it happens, but don't understand how to write correct code.

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function, you have to set up callback

Comment: This module will make your life easier: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Callbacks or promise/deferred pattern is your way to go here.

Comment: The issue is that `fs.stat` is also async.

Comment: @PaulS. There was already a `callback` in his code, but it was misused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers may work well, but they are currently quite different semantically from the original code: they both execute `stats` in parallel, rather than sequentially. The `forEach` will initiate as many asynchronous `stats` operation as there are files in the list of files. The completion order of those operations may quite well be different from the original order of the list. This may substantially affect the error handling logic.

The following approach implements a state machine, which is aimed to executes `stats` asynchronously, yet sequentially (untested):

```
function openDir(path, callback) {
    path = __dirname + path;
    fs.exists(path, function (exists) {
        if (!exists)
            callback(null, null); // node (err, result) convention
        else {
            fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
                if (err)
                    callback(err, null); // node (err, result) convention
                else {
                    var results = [];
                    var i = 0;
                    nextStep(); // process the first file (the first step)

                    function nextStep() {
                        if (i >= files.length) // no more files?
                            callback(null, result); // node (err, result) convention
                        else {
                            fs.stat(path + files[i], function (err, stats) {
                                if (err)
                                    callback(err, null); // node (err, result) convention
                                else {
                                    results[i++] = stats;
                                    // proceed to the next file
                                    nextStep();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });                   
});
```

[Promises](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) may help to reduce the nesting level of the famous ["Pyramid of Doom"](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/) like above.

Comment: promises, or the Async module :)

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez, indeed, it's good to have a choice :) This presentation may help making it: http://trevorburnham.com/presentations/flow-control-with-promises/

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `fs.stat` is also async, but you could probably do something like:

```
var result = [],
    expectedLoadCount = files.length,
    loadCount = 0;

files.forEach(function (filename, index) {
    fs.stat(path + filename, function (err, stats) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        result[index] = filename;
        if (++loadCount === expectedLoadCount) callback(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function openDir(path, callback) {
    path = __dirname + path;
    fs.exists(path, function (exists) {
        var totalFiles = 0;;
        if (exists) {
            fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                var result = [];
                files.forEach(function (filename, index) {
                    fs.stat(path + filename, function (err, stats) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        result[index] = filename;
                        totalFiles++;
                        if(totalFiles === files.length){
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

you can also use the [Async module](https://github.com/caolan/async), to help on these kinds of situations

Comment: I beat you 2 min ago =P

Comment: I use Async in many parts of my project. It is really useful and one of the best node packages ever seen.